# Convergence in probability/distribution to a constant for $X_{(1)}$ from an $\text{Exp}(1)$ population

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent and are exponentially distributed with mean $1$.

Then the CDF of the first order statistic can be found to be
$$F_{X_{(1)}}(x) = 1 - e^{-nx}\text{, } x > 0\text{.}$$
so $X_{(1)}$ is also exponential, with  mean $1/n$.

I wish to show $X_{(1)} \overset{p}{\to}0$ (in probability).

My initial thought was that convergence in probability to a constant is equivalent to convergence in distribution to a constant, so we could take
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}F_{X_{(1)}}(x)$$
and if this is equal to $0$, we're done. Well, the limit isn't $0$, as one can easily see it's actually $1$ when $x > 0$.

I get the Markov inequality proof: for all $\epsilon > 0$
$$\mathbb{P}(|X_{(1)}| \geq \epsilon)\leq \dfrac{\mathbb{E}[|X_{(1)}|]}{\epsilon} = \dfrac{1}{n\epsilon}$$
which obviously goes to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, but why doesn't the convergence in distribution trick work here?

Comment: The cumulative distribution function of the constant random variable $0$ is equal to $0$ when $x<0$, and $1$ when $x\geq 0$.

Comment: @carmichael561 -facepalm- Thank you.

Comment: It happens to the best of us